# Expresso testing on webview with href

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-instrumentation

I am trying to write some instrumentation tests on an `Android` application which has a `webview` with some contents in `href` tag.

The following is the snippet of the webview.

```
<table width="90%" class="welcome">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/demo/TransactionFree"><img
                src="/demo/pen.png" width="80" /><br /></a><b> Text <br></td>

        <td><a href="/demo/Transaction"><img
                src="/portaldemo/pen.png" width="80" /><br /></a>Text Twor</b><br> <br></td>

</table>
```

I want to click on the first item. So I wrote the following test in `Expresso`.

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='*TransactionFree']")).perform(DriverAtoms.webClick());
```

It is working on newer phones with Android, but fails on low end phones like Samsung S3. It fails to find the element.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out how to do it. Open the html page in the chrome browser -> right click on the particular element to be clicked on -> inspect element -> copy `XPath`

Will get something like this `/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/img`

Just change the `expresso` command to 
`onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/img")).perform(webClick());`

It should be clicking on that specific element.